# Animation UIImageView

Tags: xcode, animation, nstimer

I have a uiimageview and I want to move it while the animation of clock is running.The problem is when I press the button to move, the animation play the images and after the end of playing images, the image start to move 10px. It shouldn't be like this and the animation and movement should start and end together.

```
-(IBAction) MoveRightButton : (id) sender {

 [self animateRight];
[self rightTimer];

}

-(IBAction) stopRight {

[image stopAnimating];
[rightTimer invalidate];

}

-(void) animateRight {

NSArray * moveRight = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects :
[uiimage imageNamed : @"Clock1.png"] , .... , nil];

UIImage *defaultImage = [UIImage imageNamed : @"Clock1.png"];
[image setImage : defaultFace];
image.animationImages = moveRight;

image.animationDuration = 0.5;
image.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[image startAnimating];
}

-(void) goRight {
[UIView animateWithDuration : 0.5 animation : ^{
image.frame = CGRectMake (image.frame.origin.x + 10, image.frame.origin.y,image.frame.size.width, image.frame.size.height);
}];
[self stopRight];
}

-(void) rightTimer {
rightTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval : 0.5 
target : self  
selector : @selector(goRight) 
userInfo : nil  
repeats : YES];

if (rightTimer == nil) {
rightTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval : 0.5 
target : self  
selector : @selector(goRight) 
userInfo : nil  
repeats : YES];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you are doing a simple mistake please do both animation task and right going task in same animation one after other on the click of button...Use one animation block if if want it to happen at once two animation will animate at diffrent time.

```
#define StartAnimation(duration)                  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:0]

#define StopAnimation                   [UIView commitAnimations]
```

define these macro and do task between start and stop animation

Comment: sory . do u mean like : -(void) goRight {
[UIView animateWithDuration : 0.5 animation : ^{
image.frame = CGRectMake (image.frame.origin.x + 10, image.frame.origin.y,image.frame.size.width, image.frame.size.height); [self animateRight];
}];
[self stopRight];
} is that right?

Comment: and can u say how i can move my uiimageview while i keep on pressing the uibutton? the old code is like u have to press 2 or 3 times to move again and the long press isnt working since it is touch up inside